# Why ARIMA is better for shorter term forecasting compared to ECM?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

I'm reading up about the Error Correction model and was confused by the statements below, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_model):

> In order to still use the Box–Jenkins approach, one could difference
>   the series and then estimate models such as ARIMA, given that many
>   commonly used time series (e.g. in economics) appear to be stationary
>   in first differences. Forecasts from such a model will still reflect
>   cycles and seasonality that are present in the data. However, any
>   information about long-run adjustments that the data in levels may
>   contain is omitted and longer term forecasts will be unreliable.
>
> This led Sargan (1964) to develop the ECM methodology, which retains
>   the level information.

Evidently, this says an ECM should generally be preferred over ARIMA when making longer term forecasts. So my question is, why is differencing used for short-term forecasting and not good for long term forecasting?

Thanks

Comment: Hi: differencing eliminates the levels of the variables. So, if there is some long term equilbrium relationship between the levels of the two variables ( which means that the the two variables are cointegrated and this is usually what the ecm is used for. ), then an arima model isn't going to capture that relationship. Short term though , I'm not sure that any blanket generalizations can be made between ecm models and arima models.

Comment: Just to be complete, I should mention that there are cases where an ecm model can be used when cointegration is not present. If you're interested , check out Baltagi's chapter on distributed lag models where he goes into this in more detail. But I'm not so sure about the claim that arima is better than the ecm for the short term ? A good explanation of distributed lags ( which can be re-written as ecms sometimes )  and their various formulations is in Hendry's "Dynamic Econometrics."

Comment: @markleeds Thanks. This helps a lot. I was just wondering if I could ask your help in another open question that I have on CrossValidated, on the topic of ECM (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446297/can-an-ecm-be-built-such-that-new-regressors-enter-in-stage-2)